# Uber Cadence: How do I assert the call to workflow.Sleep()?

Tags: unit-testing, go, cadence-workflow

In my unit tests, I want to assert that `workflow.Sleep()` was called. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to access the emulated time using the `TestWorkflowEnvironment.Now()` function. For example:

```
before := testenv.Now()
testenv.ExecuteWorkflow(...)
after := testenv.Now()
```

Then assert on the change between `before` and `after`.